# Looking for a single word (adjective) to describe when a person expects something (yet to happen) so strongly, they act as if it is a fact

Tags: single-word-requests

Looking for an adjective that describes when a person expects something (that has not happened yet) so strongly, they act as if it is a fact (to them). This specifically involves not saying "IF" such and such, but rather just "such and such" (accepting it is a fact and refusing any other alternatives):

For example: In the film A Cinderella Story, Austin Ames does not want to play football, but his father wants him to play professional football. It has never occurred to him that Austin does not want to play football, but the idea is so strongly drilled in his head, he believes Austin want to play football, so much that he says things like
"**WHEN** you [get to football school/make it in the team]"
and
"You **ARE** throwing away your dream" (When Austin decides to leave the qualifying football match half way)

instead of saying

"**If** you make it in the team" (element of uncertainty)
and
"**Aren't** you throwing away your dream?"

The former are firm statements that completely lack any uncertainty as if what the speaker thinks, is true, whereas the latter shows the speaker has some form of uncertainty.

**The important key is this complete lack of uncertainty/questioning** (as far as the person, and only that person, is concerned, it is that way and only that way, there cannot be an alternative, even if reality is different) and the fact that this 'expectation' is forced onto the victim. The person is so certain that the thing they want (the other person to do), they don't even question it, in their mind, there is no doubt what they think, is fact (even if it is not). The adjective should also be able to be applied to the action and/or the person, such as "Austin's father was completely expectant that he will play football", or "Austin's father inundated him with --- comments every day."

I have thought of 'expect' and 'anticipate'.

The problem with 'expect' is that there is an element of uncertainty. Same with anticipate, but it sounds a little closer.

"Knew" would imply that externally, it is a fact (the word should make it clear that it is only a 'fact' within the speaker's world): "Austin's father knew Austin wanted to play football..." would mean Austin does indeed want to play football.

I thought of "anticipatory" but I would like something stronger. For example, those comments are anticipatory comments (Austin's father anticipates that Austin will play professional football).

This adjective would be frequently applicable to parents who ---- their children will become a lawyer or doctor, for example.

eg: take it for granted/just know/accept as a fact...

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean _headstrong_?

Comment: 'Over-confident'? 'Presumptuous' is a synonym, but its default sense is 'taking liberties, arrogant, not giving respect'.

Comment: They're just *parents who **assume** their children will be successful*. Or (not a single word, but *extremely common* in the specified context), ***take it for granted***.

Comment: No, not head strong or confident, which has a positive connotation meaning the person is determined to achieve their goal. I want to write about a parent who is [adjective] and forced and manipulated a child into doing what they want instead of what the child want, and made the child miserable in their career.

Comment: Can I say "he presumptuously made itinerary plans without asking the rest of the group for their ideas" to mean someone making plans as if that is decided on already, without asking the others if they want to go or not? What about "the over excited host presumptuously made plans for the tired guest" as if the host can just go ahead and make decisions for others?